# Solving recurrence T(n) = T(n/2) + Θ(1) by substitution

Tags: recursion, big-o

So I understand how to do it when the recurrence looks something like this:

T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n

In that case I would guess the answer to be O(nlogn) and then use induction to prove it. But for this one the Θ(1) throws me off. How would you do it? If you could produce the steps of induction that would be amazing.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Looks like log n to me. Just substitute, then substitute again and again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try substituting the value recursively

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + Θ(1)
 = (T(n/4) + Θ(1)) + Θ(1)  = T(n/4) + Θ(1) + Θ(1)  = T(n/4) + 2*Θ(1)
 = (T(n/8) + Θ(1)) + 2*Θ(1)= T(n/8) + 3*Θ(1)
 = T(n/16) + 4*Θ(1)
 = T(n/32) + 5*Θ(1) [ T(n/2^5) + 5*Θ(1) ]
 .                                           
 .                                           
 = T(1) + log2(n)*Θ(1)
 = O(log2(n))
```

Comment: looking for T(n) = T(n/2) + Θ(1)

Comment: @GabeJacobs, edited according to your question. check.

Comment: Please add--->`T(1)=T(1/2)+Θ(1)`,next as `T(1/2)=0;`so `T(1)=Θ(1)=constant,say 1`.